# Android Application and Timers

Tags: android, timer, android-1.5-cupcake

Hello I have an android application which has a service running. After 20 mins from that service and other systems (`such as GPS`) starting I would like it to automaticly stop. I assume I need to use a Timer for that?

Can someone show an example of how I could do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don't even need a timer for that. Just keep track of when your service was started by storing [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis() in a member variable and [`stopSelf`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf() your Service whenever you reach the timeout.

For example, include the following in your Service's busy part:

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() - TIMEOUT > startTime) {
    stopSelf();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you recommend the best place to locate this so it often run? The service in question is only a service controlling a WakeLock so its difficult to decide where to place it so the time-out will be constantly checked. Thanks.

Comment: If you really don't have a better place for it you can create your own Thread, use Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate, or the AlarmManager that was suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `AlarmManager`. Set up a single-shot alarm to go off in 20 minutes. In the standalone `BroadcastReceiver` that receives the alarm, call `stopService()`.

I have a [blog post](http://androidguys.com/?p=4411) and some [sample code in one of my books](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/) that cover `AlarmManager`, though they are all covering "the `cron` scenario", where you want to get control at boot time and set up a repeating alarm.